# If $a\equiv 1\pmod {p^2},$ then $a\equiv 1\pmod p,$ for $\,a = r^{{\rm ord}(r)}$

Tags: divisibility

I've seen this in a lot of proofs for number theory-based problems, but I can't see where they are getting it from.

If $r^{\operatorname{ord}(r)} = 1\pmod{p}$ then $r^{\operatorname{ord}(r)}= 1\pmod{p^2}$.

thanks

EDIT:

Should have been, if $r^{\operatorname{ord}(r)} = 1\pmod{p^2}$, then $r^{\operatorname{ord}(r)} = 1\pmod{p}$

I came across this when looking at this:
https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Book%3A_Elementary_Number_Theory_(Raji)/05%3A_Primitive_Roots_and_Quadratic_Residues/5.03%3A_The_Existence_of_Primitive_Roots#:~:text=Let%20p%20be%20an%20odd,p%E2%88%921%E2%88%921).

Comment: $2^2\equiv1\pmod3$ but $2^2\equiv4\pmod9$.  What is your definition of $ord(r)$?  Often $r^{ord( r)}\equiv1$ follows immediately from the definition

Comment: r is a primitive root modulo p

Comment: Well, $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod 3$ so the counterexample you were given applies.  If you want a different counterexample, then note that $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod 5$ and that $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ but $2^4\not \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$

Comment: are you asking whether a primitive root mod $p$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$?  cf. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27579/is-the-smallest-primitive-root-modulo-p-a-primitive-root-modulo-p2)

Comment: I have slightly edited the question to give some more context/ change the question.

Comment: If $p^2|r^d-1$, then surely $p|r^d-1$

Comment: Wow yes, it really was that simple! I've been working on some problems for hours and just seemed to have a mental lapse. Thank you!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title to match your corrected question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r^d\equiv1\bmod p^2$ means $p^2|r^d-1$;

since $p|p^2$, this means $p|r^d-1$, so $r^d\equiv1\bmod p$.